# Swap two parts of a dot layout

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the [following dot layout](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#%0A%0Adigraph%20%7B%0A%20%20subgraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rank%3Dsame%3B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dplain%5D%20work%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Drectangle%2Cgroup%3Dwork%5D%20w2%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rank%3Dsame%3B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dplain%5D%20main%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Drectangle%2Cgroup%3Dmain%5D%20m3%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Drectangle%2Cgroup%3Dwork%5D%20w1%0A%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Drectangle%2Cgroup%3Dmain%5D%20m1%20m2%0A%20%20edge%20%5Barrowhead%3Dopen%5D%20m2%20-%3E%20m1%20m3%20-%3E%20m2%20w1%20-%3E%20m1%20w2%20-%3E%20w1%20m3%20-%3E%20w2%0A%20%20edge%20%5Bstyle%3Ddashed%5D%20main%20-%3E%20m3%20work%20-%3E%20w2%0A%7D%0A).

```
digraph {
  subgraph {
    rank=same;
    node [shape=plain] work
    node [shape=rectangle,group=work] w2
  }

  subgraph {
    rank=same;
    node [shape=plain] main
    node [shape=rectangle,group=main] m3
  }

  node [shape=rectangle,group=work] w1
  node [shape=rectangle,group=main] m1 m2
  edge [arrowhead=open] m2 -> m1 m3 -> m2 w1 -> m1 w2 -> w1 m3 -> w2
  edge [style=dashed] main -> m3 work -> w2
}
```

[image: result of the dot above]

I would like the left part of the graph (the "work" label along with the "w1" and "w2" nodes) to be on the right part of the graph instead. I want something like this instead:

[image: This is what I want]

I tried reordering nodes and subgraphs but nothing I do makes the graph closer to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parts to this:

- swap the two columns  - use **rank=same** + an invisible edge
- move the "work" node - reversed the direction of the edge (**dir=back**)

```
digraph {
  subgraph {
    rank=same;
    node [shape=plain] work
    node [shape=rectangle,group=work] w2
  }

  subgraph {
    rank=same;
    node [shape=plain] main
    node [shape=rectangle,group=main] m3
  }

  node [shape=rectangle,group=work] w1
  node [shape=rectangle,group=main] m1 m2
  edge [arrowhead=open arrowtail=open]
  m2 -> m1 m3 -> m2 w1 -> m1 w2 -> w1 m3 -> w2
  edge [style=dashed] main -> m3
  w2 -> work [dir=back]  // reversed direction of arrowhead
  {rank=same m2 w1}      // next two reverse the order of the two columns
  m2 -> w1 [style=invis] //
}
```

Giving:
[image]